# Manually writing a tensorboard input

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a low-level API to write custom things into the tensorboard input directory?

For instance, this would enable writing summaries into the tensorboard directory without writing them from a tensorflow session, but from a custom executable.

As far as I can see, all the tensorboard inputs are inside a single append-only file where the structure of the file is not declared ahead (ie how many items we expects, what is their type, etc).
And each summary proto is sequentially written to this file through this class : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/49c20c5814dd80f81ced493d362d374be9ab0b3e/tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.cc

Was it ever attempted to manually create tensorboard input?
Is the format explicitely documented or do I have to reverse-engineer it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The library [tensorboardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboard-pytorch) provides this functionality. It was written by a pytorch user who wanted to use tensorboard, but it doesn't depend on pytorch in any way.

You can install it with `pip install tensorboardx`.